# cannot create content layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I' new to Android development. I created a new project with automatically created 'MainActivity.class', 'activity_main.xml' and 'content_main.xml'. So at this step there was no problem.

Then I'd like to create another activity called 'MainActivity2' using basic template (the one with a fab). I expect to see two layout files: 'activity_main2.xml' and 'content_main2.xml'. But it ONLY created 'activity_main2.xml'. There is no 'content_main2.xml'.

Even worse, I tried to create MainActivity2 using other templates (beside basic and empty templates), but still I cannot get 'content_main2.xml'

Where went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be because of the layout type you've selected when creating an activity in Android Studio. Nevertheless, if you would like to include one layout inside another layout you could use `<include>` tag, for example:

```
<include
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   layout="@layout/yourlayout" />
```

create a new xml layout file called `yourlayout.xml`

Comment: It didn't work. I've tried to add <include> tag in 'activity_main2.xml' but still no content_main2.xml

Comment: I'm following an online android tutorial course and it showed automatic creation of the 2nd activity_layout.xml and content_layout.xml, by clicking through new> activity >  galleries > basic activity > setting up properties, etc